# Can't POST to Django Tastypie cross-domain XHR

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, angularjs, tastypie

Trying to post to this Django Tastypie API:
http://lit-hollows-9760.herokuapp.com/api/food

I have this middleware installed to allow for cross-domain XHR:
https://gist.github.com/1369619

```
    from django import http

try:
    from django.conf import settings
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS
except AttributeError:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = '*'
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = ['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS = ['Origin', 'Content-Type', 'Accept']
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS = 'true'


class XsSharing(object):
    """
    This middleware allows cross-domain XHR using the html5 postMessage API.

    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE

    Based off https://gist.github.com/426829
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        if 'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD' in request.META:
            print request.META
            response = http.HttpResponse()
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS 
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS ) 
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS )
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS
            return response

        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        #print request.META
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS 
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS )
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS )
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS
        #print response
        return response
```

I can use JSONP to retrieve GET requests but I can't work out how to get POST to work. I just a 301 and nothing further.

```
"OPTIONS /api/food HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rob_balfre/vgrJD/

This is how I'm calling POST with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://lit-hollows-9760.herokuapp.com/api/food',
  data: '{"name": "Tapas"}',
  success: console.log('jquery worked'),
  dataType: "application/json",
  processData:  false,
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: In a very similar scenario we are getting this error from Tastypie Serializer: "Content type for specified type 'jsonp' not found. Please provide it at either the class level or via the arguments.". Any insights?

Comment: We figured out that the order in the different Django middlewares used was tampering our request before reaching the XSSharing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to add json to:

```
    serializer = Serializer(formats=['jsonp', 'json'])
```

the tastypie resource

Comment: Can you share some of the links or resources you used to workaround this. Thank you